# I have a gitlab project that needs to run integration tests in different environments (Oracle etc), how can I change the environment

Tags: grails, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, environment

```
test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - linux
    - docker
  script:
    - echo "testing"
    - ./grailsw "Oracledev test-app"
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
    name: "$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
    expire_in: 2 days
    when: always
  allow_failure: true
```

The environment name is `oracledev`, but the job is not able to set the environment to `oracledev` which is been defined in the `Config.groovy` file.

Comment: What error are you getting and from where?

Comment: Try running grails as `./grailsw -Dgrails.env=oracledev test-app`

Comment: @Daniel the console output is as follows:

Running pre-compiled script

| Script 'Oracledev' not found, did you mean:
   1) GenerateOracleChangelog
   2) Clean
   3) CleanAll
   4) AssetClean
   5) DependencyReport

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: I believe that doelleri's suggestion will fix your problem.  Grails thinks you're trying to run a command called 'Oracledev' when instead you want to run 'test-app' with the environment 'oracledev'.

Comment: @doelleri  Thank you, it worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails has three pre-defined environments: `dev`, `test`, and `prod`. To run a command in these environments, you would use `./grailsw prod test-app`.

To specify any other custom environment for a Grails command you need to use a `grails.env` system property like so:

```
./grailsw -Dgrails.env=oracledev test-app
```

You can read a little more about this in the [Environments](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/guide/conf.html#environments) section of the docs.